# Kestrel server crashes on exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, kestrel-http-server

I am using a Kestrel based server application with ASP.net core 2.1. I have a custom error handling middleware like this:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Warning(exception,"Exception occurred: {exception}",exception);

        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = exception.Message });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

It seems to work in 99% of the cases, but every now, and then the server process stops, and I see some exception as last logged entry. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce this on my development machine, it only appears on the production system. In my understanding this should not happen in any case.

Are there any known errors I could make to make the server stop? Is there anything I could enable for diagnostics?

The stacktraces of the logged exceptions usually indicate some issue with the input or things which I would like to report using the `ErrorHandlingMiddleware`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows or Liunx? If using Windows you should be able to capture a crash dump on process crash using WER (Windows Error Reporting) https://michaelscodingspot.com/how-to-create-use-and-debug-net-application-crash-dumps-in-2019/#Automatically-create-dump-on-Crash.

On Linux you can do this https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-core-dumps.html

That should let you collect a crash dump and you can analyze it to see where the crash is coming from.

Generally we catch all exceptions that happen during requests. Crashing the process usually means:

- An exception thrown from:

  - an async void method in your code
  - A background thread
- A stackoverflow exception